# Why is my cross_val_score() accuracy very high, but my test accuracy very low?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

On using the KerasWrapper, I get a very high training accuracy: above 95%

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, shuffle=True, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model(130, 130, 20000), epochs=2, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
folds = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=128)
results = cross_val_score(estimator=estimator, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=folds)
```

However, my prediction accuracy is not great at all.  Is it a classic case of overfitting?

```
prediction = cross_val_predict(estimator=estimator, X=X_test, y=y_test, cv=folds)

metrics.accuracy_score(y_test_converted, prediction)
# accuracy is 0.03%
```

How can I improve my testing accuracy? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a classic case of overfitting?

It is **not** - it's just that your process is wrong.

`cross_val_predict` is not meant to be applied to the *test* data, as you are doing here. The low accuracy is probably due to the fact that you try to retrain your model in each fold of the test dataset, which is way smaller that your training one.

The correct procedure is - fit your estimator with the training data, get predictions on the test set, and then calculate the test accuracy, i.e.:

```
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = estimator.predict(X_test)
metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Oh thank you. How do I split the data with KFold in this case then?

Comment: @AnanSrivastava you *don't* split the test set with `KFold` - you just use the whole of your test data `X_test` to get predictions and then accuracy, as shown in the answer. You can keep using `KFold` for your *training* data, as you do.

Comment: How can I use earlystopping with the wrapper? There's no callback parameter in my estimator since it is a keraswrapper.

Comment: @AnanSrivastava Please do not use the comments for irrelevant follow-up questions - you are very welcome to open a new question with the details of your issue (it's free!).

Comment: Related question: How is my Kfold getting used in model.fit(), since I am just passing X_train and y_train?

Comment: @AnanSrivastava it is *not* - `KFold` here is used to get an estimate of the accuracy of your model without using the test set

Comment: So my accuracy on training data is 95%, and my accuracy on test data is 20% after I increased the number of epochs. Why?

Comment: @AnanSrivastava difficult to tell w/o the actual data & code details; you sure apply the very same preprocessing to both training & test sets?